# Como agregarle datos a un array y que queden guardados? react js

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo un `array` al que le quiero ir agregando los valores que arroja una calculadora que tengo en otro componente.

Logro agregar al `array`, pero cada vez que se actualiza el numero, el `array` se resetea.

> 1-Mi idea es que al realizar una cuenta se guarde en el array el resultado, hago otra y que tambien se agregue, algo asi como una specie de historial del resultados.

> 2-Otra consulta es como hago para que lo que agregue al array lo pueda mostrar por fuera de la funcion? Muchas gracias!!

el codigo que hice hasta ahora:

```
const Historial = () => {
  const prec = useContext(InputContext);

  const allPrec = []
  const savePrec = () => {
    allPrec.push(...prec)
    console.log(allPrec)
  };
  console.log(allPrec)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={savePrec}>Guardar</button>
      <p>{allPrec}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Historial;
```

Codigo del otro componente (es bastante largo, tengo que revisarlo bien tambien):

```
export const InputContext = createContext()
const Inputs = ({ nombre }) => {

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    Corte: "",
    Lavado: "",
    Peinado: "",
    Color: "",
    Decoloracion: "",
    Nutricion: "",
    Manos: "",
    Alisado: "",
    Depilacion: "",
    Base: "",
    Maquillaje: "",
    Productos: "",
    Estetica: "",
    Pies: "",
  });
  const [prec, setPrec] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    setValues((state) => ({
      ...state,
      [target.name]: target.value,
    }));
  };


  const cuenta = () => {
    const corte = 0.35 * values.Corte;
    const lavado = 0.35 * values.Lavado;
    const peinado = 0.35 * values.Peinado;
    const color = 0.25 * values.Color;
    const decoloracion = 0.25 * values.Decoloracion;
    const nutricion = 0.35 * values.Nutricion;
    const manos = 0.5 * values.Manos;
    const alisado = 0.25 * values.Alisado;
    const depilacion = 0.5 * values.Depilacion;
    const base = 0.5 * values.Base;
    const maquillaje = 0.5 * values.Maquillaje;
    const productos = 0.25 * values.Productos;
    const estetica = 0.5 * values.Estetica;
    const pies = 0.5 * values.Pies;
    const pushear = () => {
      prec.push(
        corte,
        lavado,
        peinado,
        color,
        decoloracion,
        nutricion,
        manos,
        alisado,
        depilacion,
        base,
        maquillaje,
        productos,
        estetica,
        pies
      );
    };
    pushear();

    const preciosSumados = prec.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current);
    const pasando = () => {
      setPrec([preciosSumados]);
    };
    pasando();
  };
  console.log(prec);

  return (
      <div className="bordes">
        <div className="empleado-container">
          <p className="texto">Corte</p>
          <p className="texto">Lavado</p>
          <p className="texto">Peinado</p>
          <p className="texto">Color</p>
          <p className="texto">Decoloración</p>
          <p className="texto">Nutrición</p>
          <p className="texto">Manos</p>
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Corte"
            value={values.Corte}
            placeholder="35%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Lavado"
            value={values.Lavado}
            placeholder="35%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Peinado"
            value={values.Peinado}
            placeholder="35%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Color"
            value={values.Color}
            placeholder="25%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Decoloracion"
            value={values.Decoloracion}
            placeholder="25%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Nutricion"
            value={values.Nutricion}
            placeholder="35%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Manos"
            value={values.Manos}
            placeholder="50%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="empleado-container">
          <p className="texto">Alisado</p>
          <p className="texto">Depilación</p>
          <p className="texto">Base Rulos</p>
          <p className="texto">Maquillaje</p>
          <p className="texto">Productos</p>
          <p className="texto">Estética Rostro</p>
          <p className="texto">Pies</p>
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Alisado"
            value={values.Alisado}
            placeholder="25%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Depilacion"
            value={values.Depilacion}
            placeholder="50%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Base"
            value={values.Base}
            placeholder="50%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Maquillaje"
            value={values.Maquillaje}
            placeholder="50%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Productos"
            value={values.Productos}
            placeholder="25%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Estetica"
            value={values.Estetica}
            placeholder="50%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            className="inputs"
            type="number"
            name="Pies"
            value={values.Pies}
            placeholder="50%"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={cuenta}>Click</button>
        <p>Total:{prec}</p>
        <InputContext.Provider value={prec}>
          <Historial />
        </InputContext.Provider>
      </div>
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo del otro componente?

Comment: ya lo agregue!!

Comment: ¿allPrec es el array que resetea?

Comment: exacto, cada vez que se modifica prec.